# How to produce MATLAB plot (interpolation) in Matplotlib (Numpy)?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, grid, mesh

I am trying to follow a MATLAB example of meshgrid + interpolation. The example code is found [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html). On that site, I am going through the following example: **Example – Displaying Nonuniform Data on a Surface**.

Now, I would like to produce a similar plot in Python (Numpy + Matplotlib) to what is shown there in MATLAB. This is the plot that MATLAB produces:
[image]

I am having trouble with doing this in Python. Here is my code and my output in Python 2.7:

```
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.random.rand(200)*16 - 8
y = np.random.rand(200)*16 - 8
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
z = np.sin(r)/r

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x), 100)
yi = np.linspace(min(y),max(y), 200)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

Z = griddata(x, y, z, X, Y, interp='linear')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap=cm.jet)
```

Here is the result of my attempt at doing this with matplotlib and NumPy.[image: My attempt in Numpy+Python].

Could someone please help me recreate the MATLAB plot in matplotlib, as either a mesh or a surface plot?

Comment: I get this error when running your code: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2619, in griddata
    raise ValueError("output grid must have constant spacing"
ValueError: output grid must have constant spacing when using interp='linear'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the major differences in the look have to do with the default number of lines plotted by matlab, which can be adjusted by increasing `rstride` and `cstride`. In terms of color, in order for the colormap to be scaled properly it is probably best in this case to set your limits, `vmin` and `vmax` because when automatically set, it will use the min and max of Z, but in this case, they are both `nan`, so you could use `np.nanmin` and `np.nanmax`.

```
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.random.rand(200)*16 - 8
y = np.random.rand(200)*16 - 8
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
z = np.sin(r)/r

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x), 100)
yi = np.linspace(min(y),max(y), 200)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

Z = griddata(x, y, z, X, Y, interp='linear')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5, cmap=cm.jet, vmin=np.nanmin(Z), vmax=np.nanmax(Z), shade=False)
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

In matplotlib unfortunately I get some annoying overlapping/'clipping' problems, where Axes3d doesn't always properly determine the order in which object should be displayed.

[image: example result]

Comment: pseudocubic: Thanks. It appears that the limits were my main problem. I have some questions: a. I tried max(Z) and I get this: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" When I try np.max(Z) I get the same answer as np.nanmax(Z). But max(Z) is not returning NaN for me. What code did you use to see that max(Z) = NaN? b. Is there a benefit to doing this in scipy's griddata() instead? i.e. Are you aware of anything that scipy offers that would be better for such interpolation?

Comment: (a) the problem there is that you are using the builtin `max` on a `ndarray`, what you want to use is either `np.max(Z)` or `Z.max()`. (b) scipy's griddata has more options than the one included in matplotlib. I think that the matplotlib one is supposed to work more like matlab's implementation though, and in this case works fine. Personally, I always use the scipy one, but that may just be a matter of habit mostly.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: I noticed that you used "from matplotlib import cm, colors". Where did you make use of "colors"? Was that for the shading?

Comment: Ah, sorry, originally I was playing around with `norm`, but ended up not needing it. I've removed it from the example now. It would be useful if you wanted log scaling of the colors for example, `norm=colors.LogNorm()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. All questions in the full post are answered. Unfortunately, it seems like I will have to look into SciPy.